# What is the origin of the phrase "has some teeth to it"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, american-english, colloquialisms, origin-unknown

I know the phrase "has some teeth to it" refers to something that cuts and/or takes hold of something. It's used a lot in arguments / discussion of topics where serious / good counterpoints are used, and although I'm a native speaker of English I'm not able to think *or Google* it.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think *it has some teeth* is a particularly common figurative usage for *can defend itself, isn't easily dismissed or defeated* in the context of things like arguments. But it seems like pretty transparent imagery to me, so I'd expect most native speakers to understand something like *Your argument has some teeth to it* even on first encounter. Let's face it, the figurative reference is much the same as common-as-muck *Your argument is **incisive*** (penetrating, cutting, biting, like *incisor* teeth). Does it really need an "origin" or "first use"?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+teeth

Comment: It's an idiom. The top results in Google search for "have teeth" take you to the definition.

Comment: @Kris: Agreed, it's commonly used of things like ***laws, regulatory bodies***, etc., where *having some teeth* invariably means *has the power to **force** compliance*. I'm just not particularly familiar with it in the context of an argument, or "line of reasoning" (though I suppose in principle it's also much the same as *Your logic is **compelling*** (So I am *forced* to bow/concede to it).

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The figurative use of the above phrase, and similar ones, likely goes back to biblical times.  It's a very obvious analogy.

Answer (score 1):

As Kris points out in a comment above, [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+teeth) identifies "have teeth" as an idiom:

> **have teeth** if a law or organization has teeth, it has the power to make people obey it [Example:] *The committee can make recommendations but it has no real teeth.*

In U.S. legal settings, a law or regulation that is promulgated without including a meaningful enforcement mechanism is commonly referred to as being *toothless*. For example, from American Seed Trade Association, [*Year Book and Proceedings of the Annual Convention*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sv1NAAAAYAAJ&q=%22toothless+regulation%22&dq=%22toothless+regulation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI4eLbiOrrxgIVzzCICh3mcAEP) (1950):

> If there is any need for certification of garden seeds, it is nice to know that out of the fog of **toothless regulation**, one dim ray of light emerges, certification in the State of Florida. Handled by the State Department of Agriculture, and begun as **toothless in regulation** as any other, it has emerged the one complete seed certification service on the North American continent.

Conversely, the act of strengthening a statute or regulation with appropriate enforcement powers is often referred to as "giving [the law] teeth." From Jessica Warner, [*All or Nothing: A Short History of Abstinence in America*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y-0f_NnnAZEC&pg=PA65&dq=%22give+the+law+teeth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAGoVChMIxemj1urrxgIVy36ICh2gYAxg#v=onepage&q=%22give%20the%20law%20teeth%22&f=false) (2010):

> The Maine legislature had already voted for prohibition five years earlier, but it had deliberately neglected to **give the law teeth**. In 1851, the legislature again voted for prohibition. This time there was someone committed to its enforcement. The new law, moreover, did **have teeth** — crippling fines for first-time offenders, jail time recidivists, a mechanism for obtaining search warrants, and a provision for seizing black market liquor.

The expression "has some teeth to it" follows the same contours as the wordings cited above, whether it happens to be used in a fundamentally legal context or in a context not centrally concerned with laws and their enforcement. From Daniel Dombrowski, [*Rawls and Religion: The Case for Political Liberalism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GV3wFARB0FYC&pg=PA33&dq=%22has+some+teeth+to+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBGoVChMIqa33jOzrxgIVx5qICh1sfwR1#v=onepage&q=%22has%20some%20teeth%20to%20it%22&f=false) (2014):

> Let us now move to the difference principle or the maximin rule ("maximin" means *maximimum minimorum*, to maximize the status of the least members). This principle **has some teeth to it** in that it is not intended to allow someone to gain a billion dollars provided he increases the situation of the least favored by one penny. Disparities in wealth result, however, because some people are obviously more talented than others and it would be unjust not to encourage them as best we can to develop their talents.

In this last example, the metaphorical teeth being described are not measures to compel obedience (as to a law), but the force of logic that makes a principle something to be reckoned with in a philosophical argument.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought this came from a similar idea regarding another phrase "all bark but no bite." E.g. you  could make a law (bark) but did not "have teeth" to enforce (to bite).